# How to remove a decimal point and numbers after the decimal point

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have the below format specific details for some sales data.

The quantity in the sales file that will be passing through the below code has a decimal point with two numbers after it.  I would like to remove the decimal point and the numbers after, for example 1.00 becomes 1.

```
@Override
public void setFormatSpecificDetails(Sales salesRecord) {
    salesRecord.setHostStoreNumber("1");
    salesRecord.setRetailValue(salesRecord.getNetRetailValue());
    salesRecord.setDiscountValue(0);
    salesRecord.setTransactionType("SR");
    salesRecord.setQuantity(salesRecord.getQuantity());
```

Comment: You are not showing us the sales object, and you are not showing us the class containing setFormatSpecificDetails. With what is currently a random, context-less source snippet, it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I'm assuming you need to format a number. As such, look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html. There is a section **specifically** on removing the decimal separator and the numbers after it (`setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown` or even `setParseIntegerOnly`).

Comment: This code is irrelevant to the question! You could try casting it to ai int, but it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve without more detail

Answer (score 0):

```
Just Typecast the value to int or long. its very simple
                    long l =(long) salesRecord.getNetRetailValue();
                    System.out.println(l);
the code yours will be like this

      @Override
    public void setFormatSpecificDetails(Sales salesRecord) {
        salesRecord.setHostStoreNumber("1");
        salesRecord.setRetailValue(salesRecord.getNetRetailValue());
        salesRecord.setDiscountValue(0);
        salesRecord.setTransactionType("SR");
        salesRecord.setQuantity((long)salesRecord.getQuantity());
```

Comment: thrinod's comment does not work, also it is the Quantity not the RetailValue that needs to be changed.

Comment: but you didnt give correct explanation before any way i updated the result verify @StephenButlerWorrall

Answer (score -1):

You can use java.math.BigDecimal:

```
new BigDecimal("1.00").setScale(0)
```